# Modify main window's locale after user changes settings in Control Panel->Regional and Language Options

Tags: c++, winapi, ms-access-2007, locale, ado

### INTRODUCTION AND RELEVANT INFORMATION:

I have `MS Access 2007` database which I fill using `ADO`.

Among other data types ( `string`, `integer`...) I also have a `double`.

Since I work on `Windows XP` and use pure `Win32 API` to create GUI, I collect data from `edit` controls with `GetDlgItemText API` and then I convert that text into `double` using `_wtof_l`.

### PROBLEM:

Everything works well if the user sets English or Serbian ( we use European notation for decimal and group separator ) locale and **then starts the program**, but the problem occurs when user changes locale settings **while the program is working.**

Let me demonstrate this on a small example:

Let us assume that user has English locale set.

Then user starts my application.

Then user decides to change the locale ( `Control Panel->Regional and Language Settings` for `Windows XP` ) before he hits the "Save" button.

After the changes apply he then enters data and then hits "save".

The error in converting text to `double` must occur ( `_wtof_l` will now truncate `1.25` to `1` ), since my program uses default `ANSI "C" locale` and did not adapt it to reflect users modification.

### MY EFFORTS TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM:

To prevent this I need to adapt my program to the possibility described above-I need to set my locale to the one user selected before executing query.

To do so I use [message from answer to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504075/is-there-a-message-or-notification-in-win32-that-detects-when-user-changes-local) to detect when user changes settings in `Control Panel->Regional and Language Options`.

Then I use `_wsetlocale(LC_ALL,"")` to set my applications locale to the one selected by the user.

However, wrong conversion from text to decimal number described above still occurs.

This only happens when I change the locale during my program's work. If I leave locale untouched ( as 99.9% of users will ) everything seems to work fine.

To further help the community I have made a demo application that illustrates the problem.
It will be presented in the **APPENDIX** section at the end of this post.

### QUESTION:

How can I respond to `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message to set my application's locale to the one currently selected by the user so my "save" button handler can perform proper conversion from `string` to `double` with `_wtof_l` function?

Thank you.

Best regards.

### APPENDIX:

Steps to create the demo application that illustrates my problem:

1.Create `default Win32 project` in `Visual Studio`.

2.Add the following `WM_CREATE` handler:

```
case WM_CREATE:
    {
        _wsetlocale( LC_ALL, L"" ); //set current locale at window creation

        INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX iccex;
        memset( &iccex, 0, sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX) );
        iccex.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
        iccex.dwICC = ICC_STANDARD_CLASSES | ICC_TAB_CLASSES | ICC_BAR_CLASSES;
        InitCommonControlsEx( &iccex );

        // text

        HWND hEdit = CreateWindowEx( 0, L"Edit", L"", 
                         WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
                         50, 50, 150, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)8002, hInst, 0 );

        // decimal number

        HWND hEdit1 = CreateWindowEx( 0, L"Edit", L"", 
                         WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
                         250, 50, 150, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)8003, hInst, 0 );

        HWND hButton = CreateWindowEx( 0, L"Button", L"Save", 
                         WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
                         50, 150, 150, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)8004, hInst, 0 );

        SendMessage( hEdit, EM_LIMITTEXT, (WPARAM)9, (LPARAM)0 );
        SendMessage( hEdit1, EM_LIMITTEXT, (WPARAM)4, (LPARAM)0 );

    }
    return 0L;
```

3.Add the following handler to detect when user changes locale settings

```
case WM_SETTINGCHANGE:
    if( !wParam && !wcscmp( (wchar_t*)lParam, L"intl" ) )
    {
        _wsetlocale( LC_ALL, L"" ); //set it to current locale
        return 0L; // "say" we handled it
    }
    else
        break; // pass it to default window procedure
```

4.In `WM_COMMAND` handler add the following `case`s:

```
case 8004:
    {
        // initialize COM
        HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

        // format connection string
        wchar_t *bstrConnect= L"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; \
            Data Source = .\\test.accdb";

        try
        {

            ADODB::_ConnectionPtr pConn("ADODB.Connection");

            hr = pConn->Open(bstrConnect, L"admin", L"", ADODB::adConnectUnspecified);

            if ( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
            {
                wchar_t text[10], number[5];

                memset( &text, L'\0', sizeof(text) );
                memset( &number, L'\0', sizeof(number) );

                GetDlgItemText( hWnd, 8002, text, 10 );    // text
                GetDlgItemText( hWnd, 8003, number, 5 );   // double

                ADODB::_CommandPtr pCmd("ADODB.Command");

                pCmd->ActiveConnection = pConn;
                pCmd->CommandText = L" insert into MyTable ( field1, field2 ) values ( ?, ? );";
                pCmd->Parameters->Append( pCmd->CreateParameter( "?", ADODB::adDouble,
                                     ADODB::adParamInput, sizeof(double),
                                    _wtof_l( number, _get_current_locale() ) ) );
               pCmd->Parameters->Append( pCmd->CreateParameter( "?",
                                    ADODB::adVarWChar, ADODB::adParamInput, 
                                    wcslen(text), text ) );
               pCmd->Execute( NULL, NULL, ADODB::adCmdText );

               pConn->Close(); // close connection

               CoUninitialize(); // uninitialize COM
            }
            else
                throw _com_error(hr); //something failed-report it
        }
        catch(_com_error& e)
        {
            MessageBox(hWnd, (LPWSTR)(e.Description()), L"Error", MB_OK | 
                MB_ICONERROR );

            CoUninitialize();
        }

     }
     break;
```

5.Create `MS Access 2007` database in the project folder.

6.Create table `MyTable` and add 2 fields `field1` as `TEXT` field, and add `field2` which is `double`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in improper setting of the current `locale`.

I was using the wrong function to do that.

I do not wish to steal other people's credits so [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/719903/Set-main-windows-locale-to-the-locale-set-by-user?loginkey=false) is the link where I got the solution from.

This way, any time user changes local settings in *Control Panel*, my application will be able to properly convert `string` to `double` and my `INSERT` queries will not have errors!

Hopefully this will help others with the same problem.

Comment: I voted your answer up for your honesty and humility!